# normal distribution - E(X) and σ(X)

Tags: probability

A random variable $X$ is distributed normally with $E(X) = 8$ and $σ(X) =3$ .  Find $P(9≤X<11)$.

My answer:

[image]

Comment: I have to zoom a lot to see your answer but it looks perfect. (Rounding $1/3$ to $0.33$ might be considered a slight imprecision).

Comment: The procedure is correct, the numbers look right. Interpolation in my normal table would give about $0.6305$ for the probability that $Z\lt 1/3$.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer of $0.212$ is correct subject to some minor rounding as noted by the two comments to your question.  Next time you might remove some of the white space from your screengrab image so it is readable, or you could use LaTeX here.

As a check, using R you get

```
> pnorm((11 - 8) / 3) - pnorm((9 - 8) / 3)
[1] 0.2107861
```

or equivalently

```
> pnorm(11, mean=8, sd=3) - pnorm(9, mean=8, sd=3)
[1] 0.2107861
```